# Selenium C# (NUnit)- Exception not caught in catch block as [onetimeteardown] executes even if exception thrown

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, extentreports

as title suggests, i have a selenium project, sometimes for various reasons i get an ivalid unique id on the driver.close() as a solution i enclosed this in the try block, if it fails i want to catch the exception execute driver.quit() and print the exception to the test log.

As the one time tear down executes regardless of exception or not, its failing the driver.close and moving straight to onetime tear down. Any one any ideas round this, i may not run every test every run. I cant guarantee that the extent.flush will be in the right place.

I've added the code below, i think i can handle it with better logic but i cant think of how!

```
        try
        {
            TearDown();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            test.Info(e.StackTrace.ToString());
            test.Info(e.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("hello" + e.ToString());
            ForceTearDown();
            
        }


[TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        driver.Close();
        
    }

    public void ForceTearDown()
    {
        driver.Quit();
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void ExtentClose()
    {
        extent.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: TearDown() method may need to throw in order to catch that exception... (just put driver.close() in try block... or add the throws...)  I've found with the latest versions of Chromedriver in particular it's better to just call .quit().  That will close any open browser tabs/windows and dispose of the driver.  Best to check if driver is null before calling quit() just in case...

Comment: If you want to use driver.Close() for just one tab, then great, keep it. However, if you are using `driver.Close()` the same as `driver.Quit()`, you should just use `driver.Quit()` as it closes the browser * and * disposes the driver

Comment: Moving the try catch block to the tearDown method worked perfectly. thanks for that, only reason i am keeping Driver.close() is because i plan for parallel testing in the near future

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of NUnit's teardowns - both `[TearDown]` and `[OneTimeTearDown]` is that they execute whether the test passed or failed and whether an exception is thrown or not. You should not try to defeat that feature and you should not call the methods with those attributes yourself... let NUnit do the calling.

OTOH, with proper checking, both your TearDown and your test code may call `driver.Close()` or `driver.Quit` if you need to do it.